# SwiftUI dissmiss sheet with WKWebView UIViewRepresentable

Tags: swift, swiftui

today I facing one problem and it seems to be bug for me, I m unable to dismiss sheet when clicked on button inside of sheet, funny is that when I swipe down modal It dismiss, but only when I want dismiss on action it doesn't work at all

iOS 15.4.1 real device and simulator

I tried `\.dismiss`, `\.presentationMode`, but without success

my WebView Representable struct

```swift
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let url: URL?
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let prefs: WKWebpagePreferences = WKWebpagePreferences()
        prefs.allowsContentJavaScript = true
        
        let config: WKWebViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.defaultWebpagePreferences = prefs
        
        return WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        guard let myURL = url else {
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: myURL)
        uiView.load(request)
    }
}
```

sheet modifier is here

```swift
.sheet(isPresented: $showWebViewSheet) {
                ZStack {
                    // webview
                    WebView(url: URL(string: webViewURL))
                    
                    // dissmiss
                    Button(action: {
                        dismiss()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "xmark")
                            .padding(10)
                            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
                            .cornerRadius(20)
                            .padding(30)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: In that `.sheet`, add in a `.toolbar` with a button that sets `showWebViewSheet` to false. You need to have a `NavigationView` for this to work. You could also just set the variable to false in a button (see my answer).

Comment: @MrDeveloper Navigation View is as App wrapper at First view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A button with `dismiss()` **won't work**. Try this code implementation:

```swift
.sheet(isPresented: $showWebViewSheet) {
                ZStack {
                    // webview
                    WebView(url: URL(string: webViewURL))
                    
                    // dissmiss
                    Button(action: {
                        showWebViewSheet = false
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "xmark")
                            .padding(10)
                            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
                            .cornerRadius(20)
                            .padding(30)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Och this worked, i wounder why enviromental function did not, any idea?

Comment: Pretty sure that environment only works with NavigationViews not sheets.

Comment: I copied the exact code but I don't see a button to dismiss the webview, is it maybe going behind the webview? Edit: I have multiple webviews, it worked on one of them but not the others... all of the webviews load the same website!